# How to assign google script function to image button with parameter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

As the title states, I am trying to run a google script function with a parameter by clicking on an image in google sheets.

The function runs just fine as myfunc but it fails as myfunc(1)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible ..

Comment: Could you post the script you are using? Or a sample of it?

Comment: You could prompt for parameter

Comment: Use a sidebar with a textbox or select